# Need to list out members in a group to which current user belongs toin flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a flutter app in which each user belongs to only one group
my user model is as follow

```
class OurUser {
  String uid;
  String email;
  String fullName;
  Timestamp accountCreated;
  String groupId;

  OurUser({
    this.uid,
    this.email,
    this.fullName,
    this.accountCreated,
    this.groupId,
  });
}?
```

My Group model is as follows

```
class OurGroup {
  String id;
  String name;
  String leader;
  List<String> members;


  OurGroup(
      {
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.leader,
    this.members,
  });
}
```

I want to list down the members in group model based on current user.
Any suggestions on how to go forward

Comment: as in show the members of group A if the currentuser is also a member of group A?

Comment: he is also a member

Comment: what is the condition you want to specify? You say "based on current user". What does that mean?

Comment: Each user has an groupid stored in his usermodel. based on the group id i want to retrieve members(which are in string format) from Our group model

Answer (score 1):

So you must be having a List say _allGroups. To get the members you get the group first using a conditional like

```
userGroup = _allGroups.firstWhere((group) => currentUser.groupID == group.id)
```

This will give you the currentUser's group. Now you can do userGroup.members to get the members now.

```
members = userGroup.members;
```

I do not know your use case but ideally, members should of Type OurUser not String. Because members are users too right.